# Shrink one RAID-1 partition and grow another

Tags: linux, partition, raid

I have a dedicated server with `/dev/md2` being mounted on `/` with 2 TB and `/dev/md3` being mounted on `/home` with 3.5 TB.

Now I want to shrink `/dev/md2` to 500 GB and grow `/dev/md3` to about 5 TB. How do I do that? I've been able to resize `/dev/md2` to 500 GB but not changing the underlying `/dev/sd[a,b]3` to 500 GB and increasing `/dev/md3` (and `/dev/sd[a,b]4`) to 5 TB.

Output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md3 : active raid1 sda4[0] sdb4[1]
      3714478663 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        resync=PENDING
      bitmap: 28/28 pages [112KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      2111700992 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [====>................]  resync = 22.1% (467664704/2111700992) finish=144.6min speed=189433K/sec
      bitmap: 13/16 pages [52KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      33521664 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

Relevant output of `fdisk -l` (no ramdisk entries):

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 26A1CC9A-D448-41DA-AB97-926922E45FAD

Device          Start         End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1        4096    67112959   67108864   32G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2    67112960    68161535    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3    68161536  4291825663 4223664128    2T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  4291825664 11721045134 7429219471  3.5T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb5        2048        4095       2048    1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sda: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CF6FA031-2CD0-4CD6-939B-E761A2871AB2

Device          Start         End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        4096    67112959   67108864   32G Linux RAID
/dev/sda2    67112960    68161535    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/sda3    68161536  4291825663 4223664128    2T Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  4291825664 11721045134 7429219471  3.5T Linux RAID
/dev/sda5        2048        4095       2048    1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/md0: 32 GiB, 34326183936 bytes, 67043328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 511.4 MiB, 536281088 bytes, 1047424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 2 TiB, 2162381815808 bytes, 4223401984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md3: 3.5 TiB, 3803626151424 bytes, 7428957327 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: Next time use one partition and/or LVM. But here is a RAID example;  https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-resize-raid-partitions-shrink-and-grow-software-raid

Comment: That was the howto I used, sadly growing didn't work. I'm unable to use any other setup as it's automatically being set up by the hoster :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got RAID1, so if you're prepared to take the risk of disk failure during the reshape it can be done. This is not a complete recipe and you have to understand what you are doing. Even then it is quite possible you will lose data and I would **strongly** urge you to **take a backup** before you start. Really. Yes, I mean it.

The overall plan is

1. Break the RAID mirror
2. Resize the now-unused half to fit the new requirements
3. Create a new RAID half mirror with the new sized partitions
4. Copy all filesystems from the live half to the newly resized half (stop as many services as possible before doing this)
5. Reboot with the new half RAID (tricky)
6. Add back in the remaining half of the mirror to the RAID
7. Tidy up

Now, before you even consider thinking about applying this to your live system, take a backup.

While that's running, try the process out on a couple of disposable loopback disk images. Here's how to create those:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=200 > disk1.dat                          # Create a 200MB "disk"
cp -p disk1.dat disk2.dat                                            # And another

parted disk1.dat --align optimal unit MiB --script mklabel gpt       # First disk label
parted disk1.dat --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 1 2         # Dummy partition
parted disk1.dat --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 2 3
parted disk1.dat --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 3 150       # First useful partition
parted disk1.dat --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 150 100%    # Second

parted disk2.dat --align optimal unit MiB --script mklabel gpt       # Second disk
parted disk2.dat --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 1 2
parted disk2.dat --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 2 3
parted disk2.dat --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 3 150
parted disk2.dat --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 150 100%

d1=$(losetup --show --find --partscan disk1.dat); echo $d1           # Loop device
d2=$(losetup --show --find --partscan disk2.dat); echo $d2

mdadm --create /dev/md103 --metadata default --level=1 --raid-devices=2 ${d1}p3 ${d2}p3
mdadm --create /dev/md104 --metadata default --level=1 --raid-devices=2 ${d1}p4 ${d2}p4

mkfs -t ext4 -L 103 /dev/md103
mkfs -t ext4 -L 104 /dev/md104

mkdir /mnt/103 /mnt/104                                              # Mountpoints for our test filesystems
mount /dev/md103 /mnt/103
mount /dev/md104 /mnt/104
```

You'll now have two RAID1 filesystems on `/dev/md103` and `/dev/md104` onto which you can copy some data and try out the process. You've got `$d1` and `$d2` as the base names for your loop-back disk image devices.

Here is some of the detail. Has your backup finished yet?

1. Break the RAID mirror

   You can set half of the two RAID partitions faulty with commands such as

   ```
   mdadm /dev/md103 --set-faulty ${d2}p3 --remove ${d2}p3    # sdb3
   mdadm --zero-superblock ${d2}p3

   mdadm /dev/md104 --set-faulty ${d2}p4 --remove ${d2}p4    # sdb4
   mdadm --zero-superblock ${d2}p4
   ```
2. Resize the second disk partitions

   Use your preferred tool to delete and recreate the partitions on the second disk. For example,

   ```
   parted $d2 --align optimal unit MiB rm 3
   parted $d2 --align optimal unit MiB rm 4
   ```

   At this point you may well need to reboot your system. (Alternatively it's possible that `partprobe` may satisfy the requirement.) Don't forget to recreate the loop devices and assign `$d1` and `$d2` when you have done so.

   ```
   parted $d2 --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 3 50
   parted $d2 --align optimal unit MiB mkpart primary 50 100%
   ```
3. Create a new RAID half mirror with the new sized partitions

   Create the RAID devices and filesystems. Don't worry that the first one will warn you it seemed to be already part of an array - it was, but it isn't now.

   ```
   mdadm --create /dev/md203 --metadata default --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing ${d2}p3
   mdadm --create /dev/md204 --metadata default --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing ${d2}p4

   mkfs -t ext4 -L 203 /dev/md203
   mkfs -t ext4 -L 204 /dev/md204

   mkdir /mnt/203 /mnt/204
   mount /dev/md203 /mnt/203
   mount /dev/md204 /mnt/204
   ```
4. Copy all filesystems from the live half to the newly resized half

   It's important to stop as many services as possible before running this, so that the filesystems are as stable as possible.

   ```
   cp -ax /mnt/103 /mnt/203    # cp -ax / /mnt/203
   cp -ax /mnt/104 /mnt/204    # cp -ax /home /mnt/204
   ```
5. Reboot with the new half RAID

   You must update `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` with the new arrays. Use this command and add any that are not yet listed

   ```
   mdadm --examine --scan
   ```

   You will also need to update `grub` and maybe your `initramfs` so that it can find the new root filesystem. You haven't given details of these in your setup so I can't give you instructions.
6. Add back in the remaining half of the mirror to the RAID

   When you are absolutely sure you are successfully running on the new half-mirror RAID you can destroy the original half and add it back to the new half-mirrors. These commands will fail if you still have the filesystems mounted. (At this stage they shouldn't be.)

   ```
   mdadm --stop /dev/md103
   mdadm --zero-superblock ${d1}p3

   mdadm --stop /dev/md104
   mdadm --zero-superblock ${d1}p4
   ```

   Now resize the remaining disk partitions using commands like the `parted` ones above.

   Add the newly resized partitions to the new half-mirror RAID1s

   ```
   mdadm /dev/md203 --add ${d1}p3
   mdadm /dev/md204 --add ${d1}p4
   ```
7. Tidy up

   Remove the old devices from `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, `grub` and `initramfs`, and `/etc/fstab`. Reboot.

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch for the very detailed answer I'll try that out. Luckily I'm running on a completely fresh server so breaking things and retrying wouldn't be that much of a hassle (excluding time loss of course). Sadly I can't influence on how the RAID is being set up with my hosting company :/

Comment: If it's completely fresh I'd advise going RAID+LVM rather than two (or more) fixed RAID partitions. Break the RAID in the same way but instead of recreating two partitions just create one for your PV.